¿Es posible este tipo de relación? aun soy nuevo haciendo modelos ER
Hay que tener en cuenta que un paciente puede tener varias citas, pero una cita solo se puede realizar una ves, un solo paciente puede tener varias citas realizadas

No se entiende el problema, edita la pregunta y agrega detalles. Por cierto, revisa https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour

Si una cita solo se puede realizar una vez, la relación entre citas y citas_realizadas es de 1 a 1. Más allá de eso, no veo la necesidad de otra entidad, la misma entidad citas podría tener un flag que indique si se realizó o no y el resto de los datos.

Gracias por tu respuesta
